# How to display Values as Labels in Thematic Map - Mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo, thematic-map

I was able to produce the Thematic Map for Agricultural Production for the various boundaries. How can I display the production value associated with each polygon as a label (to make it look like the the pic below)

[image]?

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ArcMap, right click on the layer in your TOC > Properties > Labels > Label features in this layer (checkbox at top) > select your output attribute as the Label Field.

If you're using QGIS, right click the layer in your TOC > Properties > Labels > Show labels for this layer (dropdown on top) > Label with your output attribute.

Comment: thank you, I am using Mapinfo but was able to find a way to do it

Comment: If you found a way, add it as an answer so that the next user looking for this answer can find it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this with a workaround, by setting the labels on the original table.

So I have the original table *SchoolSite*, from which I have created the thematic map *Ind. Value with TYPE*.
I have hidden the SchoolSite table, but turned on the labels (indicated by red arrow).

[image: screen cap of MapInfo labeling]